# Why is my calculations not working?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, calculation

I am trying to solve for the variable `x`. I think I have an issue with my `D` variable. The `D` variable is supposed to add up each inputted `w`. For example, `D = w[0]+w[1]+w[2]` if there are three inputs or `D = w[0]+w[1]` if there are 2 inputs. With real values, with `goal_grade`=90.0, `exam_weight`=20, 4 extra categories, `w[1]`=10, `p[1]`=100, `w[2]`=20, `p[2]`=95.98, `w[3]`=30, `p[3]`=95.47, and `w[4]`=20, `p[4]`=96.47...`x` should equal about 62 but instead I get some giant number.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var w = [];
    var p = [];
    var C = 0;
    var D = 0;

    function addFields() {
      // Number of inputs to create
      var number = document.getElementById("category_weight").value;
      // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
      var container = document.getElementById("container");
      // Clear previous contents of the container
      while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
      }
      for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        // create a row element to contain each pair
        var row = document.createElement("div");
        row.id = 'row' + i

        row.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Category " + (i + 1) + " weight: "));
        var weight_input = document.createElement("input");
        weight_input.type = "number";
        weight_input.name = "weight";
        row.appendChild(weight_input);

        row.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Category " + (i + 1) + " percentage: "));
        var percentage_input = document.createElement("input");
        percentage_input.type = "number";
        percentage_input.name = "percentage";
        row.appendChild(percentage_input);

        // append inputs to row instead of container, then append each row to container
        container.appendChild(row);
      }
    }

    function weighted() {

      var container = document.getElementById("container");
      var rows = container.children;
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        w[i] = row.children[0].value; // or row.querySelectorAll('[name=weight]').value;
        p[i] = row.children[1].value;

      }

      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // You can do as much calculation here with w[i] & p[i]
        C += w[i] * p[i];
        D += w[i];

      }
      console.log(C);
      console.log(D);

      var x = "";
      var A = parseFloat(document.getElementById("goal_grade").value);
      var B = parseFloat(document.getElementById("exam_weight").value);


      x = (A * (D + B) - C) / B;

      if (x <= 0) {
        x = 0;
      }

      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <span>What final percentage in the class are you trying to reach or stay         above?</span>
  <input type="number" id="goal_grade" name="goal_grade" />

  <br>
  <br>

  <span>What percent is the final exam weighted?</span>
  <input type="number" id="exam_weight" name="exam_weight" />

  <br>
  <br>

  <span>How many extra weighted categories are there?</span>
  <input type="number" id="category_weight" name="category_weight" value=""> <br />
  <button type="button" onclick="addFields()">Submit </button>
  <div id="container"></div>

  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="weighted()" />

  <br>
  <br>

  <span>You will need to get <p id="result" name="r1"> </p> points out of the ... <p id="totpoints" name="tot_points"> </p> points possible on the final"
</span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tip: To improve the question try isolating the problem to only the javascript function thats not working (e.g. replace the input field with example javascript values).

Comment: Other Tip : try to give a more detailed description of the problem and what you have tried to solve it

Comment: Is this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
    C += w[i] * p[i];
    D += w[i];
```

with

```
    C += parseFloat(w[i] * p[i]);
    D += parseFloat(w[i]);
```

And you're good.

Comment: Sevindim:) But you should reconsider how you handle variables, because when you hit the button again, the function is called again making the whole calculation wrong. Try it and you'll see.

Comment: Vayyyy...Tesekkurler :)!! And i just tested it and understand what you are saying now. Is there a fast way to fix that?